# Calling SSL-enabled page from non-SSL page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ssl

I have a bit of a unique situation with a .NET MVC5 app, where I need the home/welcome page/view to render via HTTP, because there are some anchor links using images which are not deemed as secure in most browsers. So what's currently happening is that these links are not "clickable", unless you choose "show all content" in IE, and tweak some other settings in other browsers.

Clicking an image link results in a jquery modal menu, which directs the user to a "terms and conditions" modal, and if they click "confirm" an Account controller/CreateGuest method is called. I have the account controller decorated with a [RequireHTTPSAttribute], so this resource requires an HTTPS request.

It's kind of a double-edged sword, because my base controller that loads the homepage/welcome page view needs to be HTTP because of the image links, so this needs to stay non-SSL. I guess my question is, what, if anything, can be done to encrypt the "terms and conditions" AJAX call to Account/CreateGuest? I'm not really seeing too many workarounds for this because of JavaScript's same-origin policy. Or even better, is there some way to make my image links "secure"?

Here's some code:

Two of the links I want to make "secure", if at all possible. Pretty straightforward:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 homespacer">
        <div class="col-xs-2 hometype" style="text-align:right;">Some text</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 nopad">
            <a id="Type1" value="1" href='#'>
                <img style="width: 300px; float: left" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/theimage1.jpg")' />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 nopad">
            <a id="Type2" value="3" href='#'>
                <img style="width: 300px; float: right" src='@Url.Content("~/Images/theimage2.jpg")' />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 homelabeltype">Some more text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JQuery for the Terms and Conditions - the Account/CreateGuest resource call is producing the expected error in the logs: "The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL":

```
        // Create Guest account and project with selected type
    $(function () {
        $("#termsAccept").on('click', function (e) {
            kendo.ui.progress($("#floatingRectangle"), true);
            var id = $("#Type").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Account/CreateGuest/" + id,
                data: AddAntiForgeryToken({ lt: id }),
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                success: function (result) {
                    window.location.href = "@Url.Content("~/Project/Edit")";
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        })
    })
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a JQuery reference that was hardcoded to http://code.jquery.com/....etc. I changed this to a relative path and all the mixed content is coming through as https now.